# Continue with current iteration in a try-catch block | PHP

Tags: php, try-catch, break, continue

In my script there are sometimes server, connection, configuration or API problems, hence I implemented a try-catch block to properly catch Exceptions and skip them.

... but my problem isn't solved with this solution as the elements (which threw a problem) aren't the problem itself. **So basically my question is** whether there is any way to catch the error and continue where you left of: Not skipping the error and going to the next element, but to repeat the current iteration in the foreach loop.

Obviously, *continue* and *break* don't work!

```
foreach($xx as $x) {
    try {
        //main code
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        sleep(10);
    }
}
```

... and when the catch part catches the error the code is supposed to repeat the try loop with the current $x (on which it originally caught the error / threw the error) and then continue with the list of elements.

Comment: Put the try block into its own `while (true)` loop, which you can `break` on success.

Comment: could you further explain?

is your solution supposed to be:
while (true) { try {
//main code
} } 
and in the catch a break?

Comment: @deceze It probably would be better if you submit an answer with the code syntax? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the try block into its own `while (true)` loop, which you can `break` on success:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        ...
        break;
    } catch (...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This retries the same action until no exception is thrown. To avoid endless loops on actions which will simply never succeed, you can add a counter like:

```
$tries = 0;
while ($tries < 10) {
    $tries++;
    try { ... }
}
```

Comment: okay, so if I got 3 elements of which the second will randomly throw an error: the first will go as usual through the try block and will execute normally. the second iteration will trigger an error, hence in the caught block echoing me the error and sleeping 10 seconds; afterwards continuing with the same foreach iteration / element (second element) through the try block?

Comment: just tried it: works perfectly fine. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: now there's a slight chance that there will be actually an error which makes the script stop.. any way to continue after the certain item has iterated x times?

Answer (score 0):

You can run for loop instead of foreach loop and can manage the increment counter inside the catch block by decrement it to get the current $x (on which it originally caught the error / threw the error) and again retry with the same element. It may cause the infinite loop so keep any threshold of retrying.

Comment: I used a foreach loop as I'm iterating over a textfile with each line being "$x" (in the code sample above). It was the most simple solution to iterate over a text document's lines.. I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Once an exception is thrown and caught there is no way back to the block of code where the exception was thrown. So unlucky there is no technical possibility that you have just one try catch block where you catch all exceptions and then decide if they are important (and stop exection of script) or an exception was not a real problem and you want your script to behave as if there was no exception.

The only solution I can give to you is:

```
foreach($xx as $x) {
    try {
        //main code

        try {
            //first code that can cause an exception
            //you just want to continue after
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Nothing wrong, just an exception " . $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        }

        try {
            //second code that can cause an exception
            //a serious problem, you don't want to continue
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "This is a real problem " . $e->getMessage(), "\n";
            throw $e; //re-trowing exception
        }

        //third code that can cause an exception

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        //will catch exception from code 2 and 3 but not 1.

        echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        sleep(10);
    }
}
```

BTW. What you are asking for is not to be done by using exceptions but in case of errors. If an error is signaled, and it is recoverable you may write a global handler for the errors and inside that error handle decide if the error is a problem you want to shut down your script or just log it and return to the script execution as if there ware no error at all. But this is about errors, not exceptions.

Comment: right, so in the "main code", "first code" and "second code", I could write the same code..
in the solution provided by @deceze (which is working fine) there is only one small flaw: there's a slight microscopic chance that the script really stops working once / throws an exception...

Comment: @DoakCode You could write the same code but it does not make any sense. If the code you want to execute may throw an exception you don't care about then you use example `first code` if there is a code that trows an exception and you want to react to that (stop script for eg) then you use `second code` example or just leave the code as it is right now `third code`.

Comment: Jimmix - well, actually it does. Maybe I'm too bad to understand your code perfectly or it doesn't suit my situation. Either way, in my case my code can throw an exception even though the parsed element is completely fine and would go through next time (due to API limits) - thus the need of being repeated. I can't get your solution to work and went instead with @deceze's approach to take a while loop (which also fixed my latest problem that if in case a "real problem" occurs that the while loop re-tries, e.g. only 3 times). I appreciate all of your suggestion - but [at]deceze's found what I

Comment: was looking for!

Comment: @DoakCode Probably I wrongly understood your intention, with the @deceze solution you still get your code interrupted, and after the first exception let say at the line 20 of your code you will never execute line 21, 22, and all the rest of code unless there is no exception thrown at the line 20 or you put the line 20 inside try-catch like in `first code`. But at the end it is good you found a working solution that fits your needs.

Comment: no, with @deceze solution I'm able to, after getting an error, repeat the current iteration (in which the error was thrown) and continue afterwards with the next foreach iteration

Answer (score 0):

Use `while` loop with a defined number of attempts (i.e. 3).

- If exception occurs: increment attempt and re-iterate the loop.
- If No exception occurs, break the loop and go next.

My further advice is to log to track exceptions and attempts numbers.

```
$try = 0;
while($try < 3) {
    try {
        // your code here
        break;
    }catch(Exception $e) {
        $try++;

        $err = 'Exception:'.$e->getMessage().'Retrying..'.$try;
        Log::error($err); // this is Laravel log example.. can be different       
    }
}
```